# In Android manifest android:name shows me error -- parse sdk android

Tags: android, android-studio

Below is the code code of Android manifest

```
<application
        android:name="com.example.m1.parsedemo.MainActivity" // this line show error
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and the main activity java file is

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId("31e1ed2c6158fa0d01c3a5201a15e4af3f228a5b")
                // if define
                .clientKey("7d930e5059ba7ca44ce7083a6708b99eb70d9b4b")
                .server("http://35.154.249.137:80/parse/")
                .build()
        );

        ParseUser.enableRevocableSessionInBackground();

        ParseObject gameScore = new ParseObject("Manish");
        gameScore.put("score", 1337);
        gameScore.put("playerName", "Manish");
        gameScore.put("cheatMode", false);

        gameScore.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
            @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                if(e == null) {
                    Log.i("sucess","sucess");
                } else {
                    Log.i("error",e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

I am following this guideline -> [parse](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/) 
Removing

> android:name=""

shows no error, but cant connect to the server and adding it, show error. I am stuck here cant connect to parse server.

And also please tell me is there any wrong code in main activity java file.
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need this or you're referencing the wrong file  in here:

```
android:name="com.example.m1.parsedemo.MainActivity" // this line show error
```

Which you already have:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
```

If you're trying to reference the `Application` class of your project, use a different name and create another class like calling it `App`, then:

```
android:name=".App"
```

In your `AndroidManifest.xml` application tag and these codes inside the `onCreate()` of the `App` class:

```
import com.parse.Parse;
import android.app.Application;

public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
          .applicationId("31e1ed2c6158fa0d01c3a5201a15e4af3f228a5b")
          // if define
          .clientKey("7d930e5059ba7ca44ce7083a6708b99eb70d9b4b")
          .server("http://35.154.249.137:80/parse/")
          .build()
       );
  }
}
```

Just like [the documentation](https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/).

Answer (score 1):

This should be name of your application class, not the activity class

```
<application
    android:name="com.example.m1.parsedemo.MainActivity" // this line show error
</application
```

correct it with the application class which looks like this

```
public class App extends Application {
  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
      .applicationId("YOUR_APP_ID")
      // if defined
      .clientKey("YOUR_CLIENT_KEY")
      .server("http://localhost:1337/parse/")
      .build()
    );
  }
}
```